# How to get rid of symbol file related warning/error messages

Tags: windbg, symbols, dump, pykd

I'm debugging dumpfiles, using `Windbg`, and regularly I'm getting warning/error messages, like the following:

```
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for icuuc58.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for icuuc58.dll -
```

In order to avoid those, I've already tried to proceed my whole processing with:

```
!sym prompts off
!sym quiet
```

But the warning/error messages keep arriving.

**Edit after first reply** (is confirmed in second edit)

I've done several attempts, using `.outmask-6` and `.outmask-206`, but all of them more or less failed. What does that mean:

```
.reload -f => a lot of error/warning messages                      => normal behaviour

.outmask-6 or .outmask-206
.reload -f => no error/warning messages                            => Ok

.outmask-6 or .outmask-206
.reload -f => no error/warning messages                            => Ok
<execution of the whole script> => a lot of error/warning messages => NOK
```

I believe there are commands, which disable `.outmask` command. Can you confirm this and in case yes, is there a command like:

```
.outmask-206(global) (which applies for the whole Windbg session)
```

As far as the `symsrv.ini` file is concerned: I don't have this file on my computer, and honestly I prefer not to be searching for every module which symbol loading might cause problems. I'd prefer just to avoid the mentioned warning/error messages.

**Edit after more insight on the issue**

One thing I didn't mention yet, is the `PYKD` usage: I'm working on heap_stat, a script, based on PYKD, for performing memory analysis, and I believe the problem in here, as you can see in following excerpt:

Script source code:

```
dbgCommand(".outmask-206")
...
dprintln("1")
type_info = typeInfo(class_name)
dprintln("2")
```

Script output:

```
1
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for icuuc58.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for icuuc58.dll -
```

In my opinion, this means that the `PYKD` `typeInfo()` object declaration is the one, disabling the `.outmask()` `Windbg` command.

@PYKD developer: can you confirm this and if yes, add a `PYKD` issue for this? (I didn't see any `.outmask` related issue on the [`PYKD` issues homepage](https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd/issues))

Comment: Does it change if you force a symbol reload (`.reload`, `.reload /s /f icuuc58.dll` and maybe even `.reload /f`) after the `!sym` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now, there've been two answers to my question:

- Outmasking general `Windbg` command output
- Outmasking `PYKD` command output

I can't use general `Windbg` outmasking, as I'm using `PYKD` commands.
I can't use `PYKD` outmasking, as I'm just launching (thousands of) `PYKD` commands, which are, every single time, opening and closing a separate `PYKD` session, and configuring the `PYKD` outmask would slow down my application too much.

Therefore I've decided to go for another approach: I'll make sure that the `PYKD` output messages' format is so specific (it will always contain a TAB character) that, instead of not using the error messages, I'll decide only to use the `PYKD` messages (the ones, containing the TAB characters).

I've tested this approach and I can confirm it's working fine.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

you can suppress the error / warning messages with **.outmask-6**
or with **.outmask-206** to suppress the symsrv summary at the end and the warning messages

```
0:049> .outmask-6
Client 02C95358 mask is 3F1
0:049> .reload /f
Reloading current modules
................................................................
............................................................
```

be careful when using this some important error messages may also be suppressed

if you mean you need to stop symsrv from hitting the ms symbol server and wasting time

set up a symsrv.ini with [exclusions] section

```
cd windbg installation path

echo [exclusions] >> symsrv.ini
echo ic* >> symsrv.ini
```

outmask is global setting

[image]

Comment: outmask is a parameter for IDebugControl::ControlledOutput method
it is a global dbgeng!g_LogMask  see the gif i edited in

Answer (score 1):

PYKD set own output mask:

```
 client->GetOutputMask(&oldMask);  
 client->SetOutputMask(DEBUG_OUTPUT_NORMAL|DEBUG_OUTPUT_ERROR|DEBUG_OUTPUT_WARNING|DEBUG_OUTPUT_DEBUGGEE );
```

Comment: It is from C source code.It can not be tuned. We can change it but first we need to understand why it was made.

Comment: try  to update pykd bootstarpper:
https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd-ext/wikis/uploads/d037985af53cb77606c2a20e9901a51d/pykd_ext_2.0.0.20.zip